# Problems with socket communication between projects, inUTF not working

Tags: java

I am trying to connect two projects using sockets, but on the method that establishes said connection and asks for something to the other project (in this case a boolean) it gives me an error. I belive it could be a problem of the inUTF. This is the method:

```
@Override
    public boolean login(String mail, String comprueba){
        System.out.println("Estoy en el facebook login");
        System.out.println(comprueba + mail);
        String data = mail + DELIMITER + comprueba;

        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverIP, serverPort);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("a");
            out.writeUTF(data);
            System.out.println("b");

            boolean valid = in.readUTF().equals("true");//if server says true, then it is valid
            System.out.println("c");
            return valid;
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

And this is the error it gives me:

```
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:593)a
     [java] b
     [java] false   at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:568)
     [java] MIRA ESTOfalse
     [java]     at es.deusto.ingenieria.sd.strava.external.FacebookService.login(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at es.deusto.ingenieria.sd.strava.server.services.LoginAppService.login(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at es.deusto.ingenieria.sd.strava.server.remote.RemoteFacade.login(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
     [java]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
     [java]     at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
     [java]     at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
     [java]     at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
     [java]     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
     [java]     at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
     [java]     at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
     [java]     at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
     [java]     at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
     [java]     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
     [java]     at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
     [java]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
     [java]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
     [java]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: The stacktrace shown is incomplete, and please provide a [mre]. Also, make sure both sides of the connection are actually using `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream`, as these are specialised streams for a specific binary serialization format of data types. It is not a general purpose tool to read data.